# Rails 3 - Ancestry gem method arrange not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

---

hi people

I've follow this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

when I tried to make the "arrange (:order => :id)" I got this message

```
    undefined method `arrange' for #<Array:0x8c19780>

Extracted source (around line #4):

1: 
2: <h1>Listing categories</h1>
3: 
4: <%= nested_categories @categories.arrange(:order => :id) %>
5: 
6: <br />
7:
```

Can you help me, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using the ancestry Gem , and it works fine for me. e.g.:

```
 require 'awesome_print'                  # just for nice demo output
 ap  Account.arrange(:order => :id) ; 1
```

You need to run it on your Categories class itself -- it's a class method

try it out in the Rails console!

Comment: so, the railscast is wrong??... do I have to change anything else in my code, because I did exactly the same steps. And where should I write that code you give me as example, in Model or Controller??

Answer (score 3):

I'll clarify @Tilo's answer:

In your Controller, do:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.arrange(:order => :created_at)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @categories }
  end
end
```

And in your View, do:

```
<%= nested_categories @categories %>
```

I'm using Rails 3, and the "Ancestry" gem seems like a great replacement for the "Acts As Tree" gem.

Answer (score 1):

As I have described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887471/ancestry-gem-undefined-method-error) ...

The arrange() method acts either at the class level or on a named scope, not on a returned array of values. For example, if you want to call arrange() on a table called 'Activity', this would work and return the entire table in an arranged format:

```
Activity.arrange
```

However, if you want to call arrange on a specific tree in the table you would go:

```
Activity.find(...).subtree.arrange
```

'subtree' is a named scope provided by the has_ancestry gem. Therefore, the arrange() method should work for the following named scope:

- ancestors
- children
- sibblings
- descendants
- subtree